# How to make a periodic task in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a function that is printing reports to the console with `fprintf`. But it's writing a lot, making it impossible to follow with the eye. So I want to make it "slower", or decrease the amount of writing. Can I make a decision based on `mod(current_time, something)`?

So what I want to achieve is, the system should go verbose for 0.5 seconds, then go silent for 1 second, and repeat.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not write to a log file? You can then examine it at your own pace. It is better then throwing away messages which might be important

Comment: What information is being printed? A common trick is, if this is over a series of iterations and you want to keep track of progress, to only print ever, e.g. 100 iterations or if total number is known, then to print 10%, 20%...